# OpenGL procedural texture antialiasing

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, pyopengl

I`ve made a grid using a simple GLSL shader, passing **texture coordinates** to **fragment** shader. It was applied onto a large scaled plane.

Fragment shader:

```c
#version 330 core

out vec4 fragColor;

smooth in vec2 f_TexCoord;

vec4 gridColor;

void main()
{
    if(fract(f_TexCoord.x / 0.0005f) < 0.025f || fract(f_TexCoord.y / 0.0005f) < 0.025f)
        gridColor = vec4(0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 1.0);
    else
        gridColor = vec4(0);
    // Check for alpha transparency
    if(gridColor.a != 1)
        discard;

    fragColor = gridColor;
}
```

[image]

As you can see the lines are not smooth and they start to **"flickering"** at the horizon.
Is it possible to apply some sort of filtering/antialiasing on it? I've tried to increase number of samples (up to 4, because higher values gives me a qt error), but it has no affect on shader.

Comment: Maybe this article about [filtering procedural textures](https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/filtering/filtering.htm) is helpful to you.

Comment: I've worked with similar application which needed grid lines to be drawn. I ended up using geometric lines in a single draw call. This was much efficient and accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to GLSL version 4.20 (at least), activate multisampling and use the [Auxiliary Storage Qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#storage-qualifiers) `sample` for the vertex shader output (and fragment shader input):

```c
#version 420 core

sample smooth in vec2 f_TexCoord;
```

The qualifier causes per-sample interpolation.

Comment: works quite well. Unfortunately, works only with version 420+. In other case, shader compilation fails with this error: `auxiliary storage qualifiers must come just before storage qualifiers`. Anyway, BIG thanks for this hint!

Comment: @Artem Thank you (fixed 4.00 -> 4.20). You're welcome.